# Is there a ternary conditional operator in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What are alternatives to implement the following query:

```
select *  
from table  
where isExternal = @type = 2 ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: @JFA - no, *a* ternary operator is any operator that takes three operands. In most languages, *if* they have any ternary operators, it's common that they have only one, that is (generally) called the conditional operator. Calling things by the wrong name (or using a general name when you mean a specific) can just lead to more confusion. For further guidance, please consult the [tag:ternary-operator] tag wiki.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation : see "THE ternary operator"

Comment: OP used the common name for a thing, not its wrong or too-general name.  I disagree with your conclusion that professionals (for whom this site was built) will be confused by this, when it is indeed commonly used terminology.

Comment: @TimothyKanski, while Damien may be coming off as a bit of a smart ass, the OP did specifically ask for "a ternary operator" not "THE ternary operator". ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Use `case`:

```
select *
from table
where isExternal = case @type when 2 then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 220):

In SQL Server **2012**, you could use the [`IIF` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE isExternal = IIF(@type = 2, 1, 0)
```

Also note: in T-SQL, the assignment (and comparison) operator is just `=` (and not `==` - that's C#)