# How to use ternary operator in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Account 
WHERE (type <>100000002 ? Id='something': Id=null)
```

but it shows error :

> Incorrect syntax near '?'

Please help me.

Comment: dear way not you use the CASE statment or IF Else

Comment: if you need the example or CASE or IF Else then let me know i will send you the example

Comment: `where (type <>100000002 and Id='something') or (type =100000002  and id is null)`

Comment: IS this what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209751/is-there-a-ternary-operator-in-t-sql

Comment: @Punter015 no it's not. he has null there. ( unless you can do `=null`)

Comment: There's no ternary operator in T-SQL.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is for SQL Server. `IIF` is not available in SQL Server 2008 or earlier.

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM Account 
    WHERE 
    Id=IIF(type<> 100000002,"something",null )
```

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or earlier, then try this.

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM Account 
    WHERE (Id= CASE WHEN type <>100000002 THEN 'something'  ELSE null END)
```

Comment: If you consider best practices you should avoid using IIF because its a function and it is slower than CASE WHEN statement

Answer (score 5):

You can do this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Account 
where (type <>100000002 and Id='something') or (type =100000002 and id is null)
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM Account 
where  isnull(id,'_null_')= case when type <>100000002 then 'something' else  isnull(id,'_null_') end
```

Comment: +1 for the first T-SQL, Simple T-SQL for Simple Logic

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Account 
WHERE (Id= CASE WHEN type <>100000002 THEN 'something'  ELSE null END)
```

Comment: you cant always do `id=null`

Comment: However, note that with ANSI nulls, this will probably not work as intended, since `null = null` is actually false. You have to use `Id is null` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Account 
WHERE (Id= CASE WHEN type != 100000002 THEN 'something'  ELSE null END)
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM Account 
WHERE (Id= CASE WHEN type <> 100000002 THEN 'something'  ELSE null END)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Account 
where (type <>100000002 and Id='something') or (type =100000002)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use case when...then in sql please see this link
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/14/sql-server-case-statementexpression-examples-and-explanation/